# Unable to query from non-Apollo GraphQL server from Apollo client

Tags: graphql, apollo

I tried to make a request using Apollo Client into non-Apollo GraphQL server as below:

```
import ApolloClient, { createNetworkInterface } from 'apollo-client';

// Register gql globally
import { registerGqlTag } from 'apollo-client/gql';
registerGqlTag();

const networkInterface = createNetworkInterface(' http://localhost:8080/graphql', {
  headers: {
  'Content-type': "application/json"
  }
});

var client = new ApolloClient({
  networkInterface
});

client.query({
  query: gql`
    query getTodo($todoId: Int!) {
      node(id: $todoId) {
        ... on Todo {
          id
          text
        }
      }
    }
  `,
  variables: {
    todoId: "todo:100000",
  },
  forceFetch: false,
}).then((graphQLResult) => {
  var errors  = graphQLResult.errors;
  var data = graphQLResult.data;

  if (data) {
    console.log('got data', data);
  }

  if (errors) {
    console.log('got some GraphQL execution errors', errors);
  }
}).catch((error) => {
  console.log('there was an error sending the query', error);
});
```

However I keep getting an error while running the code:
`there was an error sending the query [ReferenceError: fetch is not defined]`

I try to search the issue related to that, however the documentation doesn't really helpful.

Thanks before.

Comment: I got a response from an Apollo member related to this issue, https://github.com/apollostack/apollo-client/issues/177

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Behind the scenes, the Apollo client uses `fetch` which is a new standard around making http requests. It is present in most major browsers but its not found in node or IE / Edge. The team made the call to go with fetch because its adoption is growing and the availability of polyfills for older browsers and node.

We added a section to the docs around this issue here: http://docs.apollostack.com/apollo-client/core.html#fetch-polyfill

For some insight into the decision to go with fetch, check out this issue: https://github.com/apollostack/apollo-client/pull/126

Comment: Current discussions can be found here: https://github.com/apollostack/apollo-client/issues/269 and https://github.com/apollostack/apollo-client/issues/645

(The first link in James' answer is dead)

Answer (score 1):

If you're working in node environment you need to add fetch to `global`object:

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

global.fetch = fetch;
```